# Dagger 2.15 - How to inject a dependency in Application class

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I am unable to inject a depency in DaggerApplication class

The relevant classes are as follows

Application

```
class App : DaggerApplication() {

@Inject lateinit var mSomeClass : SomeClass // This is always NULL

override fun applicationInjector(): AndroidInjector<out DaggerApplication> {
    return DaggerAppComponent.builder().application(this).build()
 }


override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()

    mSomeClass.initialize()  // mSomeClass is NULL
}
```

Component:

```
 @Singleton
 @Component(modules = [
    AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
    AppModule::class,
    ViewModelFactoryModule::class,
    BuildersModule::class
  ])
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<DaggerApplication> {

@Component.Builder
interface Builder {

    @BindsInstance
    fun application(application: Application): Builder

    fun build(): AppComponent
    }
}
```

AppModule class:

```
    @Module
    class AppModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideSomeClass(context: Context) = SomeClass(context = context)
}
```

Not sure what is missing.

Comment: you have a mixture of java and kotlin there, please precise a full with the language are you trying

Comment: `void inject(App app);` and `appComponent.inject(this)`

Comment: Please include your component interface.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce, Could you please elaborate on your statement?

Comment: Pretty sure this should be `interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<App>`

Comment: @silent_control can you find a solution? I have the same problem

Answer (score 18):

I experienced the same problem and figure out that we can not call `inject(this)` in `Application` class when using `DaggerApplication` in `AppComponent`. Because of this, we can not inject anything I think.

So in the AppComponent you have to specify your `Application` Class instead of typing `DaggerApplication`

Your `AppComponent` should be like this

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AndroidSupportInjectionModule.class, AppModule.class})
public interface AppComponent extends AndroidInjector<MyApplication> {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        @BindsInstance
        Builder application(Application application);
        AppComponent build();

    }

}
```

And your `Application` class

```
    public class MyApplication extends DaggerApplication {

        @Inject
        SomeClass mSomeClass;

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            mSomeClass.initialize();
        }

        @Override
        protected AndroidInjector<MyApplication> applicationInjector() {
            AppComponent appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder().application(this).build();
            appComponent.inject(this);
            return appComponent;
        }
        }
```

Now you can inject in `Application` class.

Little note: If I said something wrong please correct me, I am not expert about Dagger :)

Comment: very shocked this worked.  there is nothing wrong with what you said, you are an expert in dagger in my eyes.  tysm

Answer (score 0):

You should implement HasActivityInjector and its methods. The example is at the below. Hope will work.

```
class App : Application(), HasActivityInjector {

@Inject
lateinit var dispatchingAndroidInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity>

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()

    DaggerAppComponent
            .builder()
            .create(this)
            .inject(this)
}

override fun activityInjector(): AndroidInjector<Activity>? {
    return dispatchingAndroidInjector
}
}
```